# Python Flask Set Text in Website without reloading

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask

I've created a simple flask application.
I won't show it here because there is much Bootstrap stuff in it.

My website shood look so:

```
Installation will be done...
> Installing Flask-Nav
```

After the first extension is installed:

```
Installation will be done...
> Configuring Flask for Extensions
```

And so on...

But there is also bootstrap stuff on the website. So it takes some second to load the page. But i only want to set the status label. How can i do that without refreshing the whole Page?

```
def install():
    download("flask-nav")
    config("flask-nav")
    setstatus("> Downloading next extensions") #How to do that???
    download("flask-appconfig")
    ....
```

Comment: You'll need to use websockets and DOM manipulation.

Comment: Can you explain please how to do that? Code example?

Comment: ...maybe [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))?

Comment: I am beginner to web development. So i know ajax but i don't know how to use it with flask

Comment: Actually I also didn't try, but [here is the document](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/jquery/).

Comment: Thank you but i don't really know how to use it. Could anybody post an example for my question please?

Comment: From your problem statement I feel using websockets would be a better solution than ajax. You could check this [link](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent) for better understanding of using websockets with Flask. Since, updates will be sent mainly from server side, hence I suggested websockets. If AJAX was to be used then the client would continuously be polling the server for updates, which is not a good scenario.

Comment: Is there a more simple way to do that?

Comment: If you don't want the page to refresh, then using either websockets or AJAX calls will solve your issue.

Comment: Ok, can you please post an exanple for me how to do that with my code? I will accept your answer. I would like to have the simplest solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a very simple implementation of Flask-SocketIO. You can follow this [article](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent) for better understanding

*test.py*

```
import time
from threading import Thread

from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask.ext.socketio import SocketIO, emit

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)
thread = None


def background_thread():
    """Here is where you'll perform your installation"""
    count = 0
    # Call Install function 1 using time.sleep(10) to simulate installation
    time.sleep(10)
    count += 1
    socketio.emit('my response',
                      {'data': '1 installed', 'count': count},
                      namespace='/test')

    # Call Install function 2 using time.sleep(10) to simulate installation
    time.sleep(10)
    count += 1
    socketio.emit('my response',
                      {'data': '2 installed', 'count': count},
                      namespace='/test')

    # Call Install function 3 using time.sleep(10) to simulate installation
    time.sleep(10)
    count += 1
    socketio.emit('my response',
                      {'data': '3 installed', 'count': count},
                      namespace='/test')


@app.route('/')
def index():
    thread = Thread(target=background_thread)
    thread.start()
    return render_template('index.html')


@socketio.on('disconnect', namespace='/test')
def test_disconnect():
    print('Client disconnected')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app)
```

*templates/index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Flask-SocketIO Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Flask-SocketIO Test</h1>
    <div id="log1"></div>
    <div id="log2"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/0.9.16/socket.io.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            namespace = '/test';
            var socket = io.connect('http://' + document.domain + ':' + location.port + namespace);
            $('#log1').html('<br>Installing Software');
            $('#log2').html('<br> > ...');
            socket.on('my response', function(msg) {
                $('#log2').html('<br> > Received #' + msg.count + ': ' + msg.data);
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Notice, the `background_thread()` function. That is the function where you'll call your installation functions and emit a response whenever an installation completes.

Comment: @Faminator -  Follow the [link](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-websockets-with-flask-and-gevent) and the above example. If you still have some doubts then comment here below. I'll help out.